# google provider sign in with supabase auth

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, next.js, oauth-2.0, supabase

sigining in with next_auth and a google provider sends me to the "site URL configuration" setting.

(the main site URL)
with an access token at the end of the URL.

Siging in on the same page with normal means works fine.

I am using the supabse "nextjs auth helpers"

I have everything working normally outside of google.

I have everything set up correctly according to the youtube videos and docs after checking over and over a few times.

after reaching the page:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?

in which you choose your google account.

the redirect after goes to the redirect emails send you to, but does not have the person logged in.

I cant figure out why this is, the token should have been used to log in.

```
      const [supabaseClient] = useState(() =>
createBrowserSupabaseClient(
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
)
```

has just been corrected to :

```
  const [supabaseClient] = useState(() =>
    createBrowserSupabaseClient({
      supabaseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
      supabaseKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
    })
  );
```

Comment: Try a different browser, I had a similar issue with password reset logging in and in Firefox it does not log the user in (even tho the token is sent) where as in chrome it does. Also, are you forsure seeing the token in the URL fragment right after redirect?

Comment: ass per suggestion, i just tried with edge.
here is the URL:

https://biohacking-cirostratus.vercel.app/MemberPage

if you want to try logging in with google and see if it works...

Comment: ok so I see the URL fragment with the token but from what I can tell it seems like the supabase client is not parsing it and setting the session, are you initializing the supabase browser client at the root of your app?

Comment: I found something funny in the root initialisation, but signing in with email and password always seemed to work anyway.

Comment: large chance you have just fixed it. ill post my problem.

at _app

I did this:

Comment: you modified the params and it made it work?

Comment: seems to work once, and then if i change any of the things like profile pictures etc, it returns to being just as bad as it was before now.

Comment: its honestly very confusing, but i think somehow i also corrected a spelling mistake, or something similar.

Comment: basically, now when i load the page, if I pick a new user, then it works, if I pick a user I just added a photo in it doesn't work but regardless it now no longer shows the access token in the URL, it seems to be approved and used based on the network tab

Comment: ok, it seems to randomly work now. I think ill delete all cache and cookies again.

thanks so much for all the help, the problem really was where you said it was and the original case cookie thing seems to be the issue now

Comment: no problem! Also, i see that where you changed the params to be an object instead of strings, that should give you an error if you are using typescript. So if you aren't already doing so I would recommend it, this is a prime example of why typescript is so useful :D